# Should follow-up answers be comments?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I was just about to flag [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40621375/937377) as "Not an answer," since it would better have been a comment on the first answer, but paused, wondering if I should really flag it so, since he was indeed *contributing* to an answer to the question, even if it isn't complete alone.

What should be done with such "answers?"

Comment: Would the answer still be an answer if *"To follow up on Ilia luk's answer,"* was removed? *"PHP Storm now has Twig support built-in, just enable the plugin if it isn't."*

Comment: Note that *any* attempt to answer the question is an answer and therefore doesn't qualify for NAA unless it's a link only answer that can't survive if the link was broken. Being incomplete just makes it less useful or lower quality.

Comment: @KevinB Point taken. However, without the first answer's context, the second answer looks like it's replying to an entirely different question. So would the correct course of action be to edit to expand the answer?

Comment: The main thing that answer was missing was a link back to the answer it was referencing. I edited that in, and it's now fine. I was *very* tempted while editing to just remove the "To follow up on…" part altogether, since it doesn't actually seem like it's a follow-up at all, but I didn't do it because I don't know the technology involved at all and as a result, wouldn't feel comfortable making drastic changes to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either comment or answer is fine. If the followup completely replaces existing answer posting a new answer is better as it allows to vote on the new suggestion separately.

Readable followup answer is definitely "attempt to answer" - so don't try to flag as NAA (unless it is link only without actual useful followup "{link to answer} is wrong"). Depending on quality of the post - you may consider downvote (and vote as VLQ if you fill it deserves deletion) or comment or edit.

For this particular case answer looks self-sufficient without reference to the other answer - so no flagging applies. Consider to vote on the content of the post if you actually know the topic. Note that author had no reputation so could not post it as comment (which would be perfectly fine too).

If you feel to improve that answer - either remove reference to other answer (as it actually don't seem to add any value) or change reference to the other question to link and provide half-line summary like "{link} that suggested to use Twig plugin".

Comment: Very agreed with the last paragraph. Any references to other posts, especially if they're not linked, are at best contributing to confusion and add nothing. An answer should be self-contained and only refer to other material if it's needed to support the content of the answer.